# Regex R: Word-boundary and separated characters

Tags: r, regex

I am using `gsub` to replace words in a vector in R following the idea of a dictionary. That is, a given sets of words (synonyms) `syn = c("Cash", "\\$")`, are supposed to be replaced by a word (`word = "MONEY"`).

```
text <- c("I spent 100$", "Cash can be used", "Cashier doesnt count", "a separate $")
```

So far I am using this to replace the synonyms:

```
syn <- c("Cash", "\\$")
word <- "MONEY"

regex <- paste0("\\b(", paste(syn, collapse = "|"), ")\\b")
# "\\b(Cash|\\$)\\b"

gsub(regex, word, text)
# "I spent 100MONEY"     "MONEY can be used"    "Cashier doesnt count" "a separate $"
```

Which works in the case where the $-sign is attached to alphanumerics, but fails if the sign is separated. If I abandon the word-boundary (`\\b`), then the $-sign is found, but so is "Cash" in "Cashier".

Do you know how I am able to have a word-boundary but also find the single $-sign?

Comment: So, you expect `[1] "I spent 100$"         "MONEY can be used"    "Cashier doesnt count" "a seperate MONEY"  `?

Comment: Almost, I expect `c("I spent 100MONEY", "MONEY can be used", "Cashier doesnt count", "a seperate MONEY")`

Comment: But `$` in the first string is preceded with a digit. How are word boundaries defined here? Not inside letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom boundaries with a PCRE regex:

- `(?<!\p{L})` - beginning of a word (no letter before)
- `(?!\p{L})` - end of a word (no letter after)

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/R48Kcz/2).

Sample R code:

```
> text <- c("I spent 100$", "Cash can be used", "Cashier doesnt count", "a seperate $")
> syn <- c("Cash", "\\$")
> word <- "MONEY"
> regex <- paste0("(?<!\\p{L})(?:", paste(syn, collapse = "|"), ")(?!\\p{L})")
> gsub(regex, word, text, perl=TRUE)
[1] "I spent 100MONEY"     "MONEY can be used"    "Cashier doesnt count" "a seperate MONEY"    
>
```

Comment: I also advise to use a *non-capturing* group (`(?:...)`) to wrap alternatives since you are not using the capture anywhere, thus, no need using a *capturing* group.

Comment: Wonderful, that does the job, thank you very much for the fast answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
regex <- paste0("\\b", paste(syn, collapse = "\\b|"))
#"\\bCash\\b|\\$"
gsub(regex,word,text)
#[1] "I spent 100MONEY"     "MONEY can be used"    "Cashier doesnt count" "a seperate MONEY"
```

Comment: While this may provide code to solve the question it would be much more useful if you added some explanations of what this code does and how it solves the question.